# How to stream the contents of a gnome window

Tags: video-streaming, gnome

I have a window open in Gnome/Ubuntu, and would like to stream its contents to a website. Does someone here on SO know how to do that?

I'm open to pretty much any programming language as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: Is the window part of an application that you're writing or do you have to do it from a separate program?

Comment: It's a separate program that produces visual output from my commands.

Comment: Then I would look for something that lets you take screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GTK+ HTML backend, which is still under development.  The backend is known as *Broadway*.  This backend runs the application in a webbrowser, but you can check the code to get what you want.  Check the [explanation and demo of Broadway](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/).

Comment: Keep in mind that this will limit the web site to a single viewer at a time.  When a second person browses to the site, the first person will be disconnected.